# Python: Check for write only attr of a Class

Tags: python

I'm using a Class provided by a client (I have no access to the object code), and I'm trying to check if a object has a attribute. The attribute itself is write only, so the `hasattr` fails:

```
>>> driver.console.con.input = 'm'
>>> hasattr(driver.console.con, 'input')
False
>>> simics> @driver.console.con.input
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Attribute: Failed converting 'input' attribute in object   
'driver.console.con' to Python: input attribute in driver.console.con 
object: not readable.
```

Is there a different way to check if an attribute exists?

Comment: thinking of EAFP, could you wrap it in a `try` block and except `AttributeError` if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Does it say "not readable" if you try accessing an attribute that you haven't created? If it does, you could just check if the message of the exception object contains `not readable`.

Comment: @RichSmith That's currently the way I was thinking of attacking the problem. I'm also wondering what's behind this.

Comment: @Blender The object is full created at this point. I can write to it but not read.

Comment: @ArikRinberg: you can't read from the object, but does the error message differ when accessing an attribute you've previously written and when accessing an attribute that you have not?

Comment: @Blender no it does not. It always shouts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have some kind of native code proxy that bridges Python to an extension, and it is rather breaking normal Python conventions

There are two possibilities:

1. The `driver.console.con` object has a namespace that implements attributes as [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), and the `input` descriptor only has a [`__set__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set__) (and possibly a [`__delete__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delete__)). In that case, look for the descriptor:

   ```
   if 'input' in vars(type(driver.console.con)):
       # there is an `input` name in the namespace
       attr = vars(type(driver.console.con))['input']
       if hasattr(attr, '__set__'):
           # can be set
           ...
   ```

   Here the [`vars()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) retrieves the namespace for the *class* used for `driver.console.con`.
2. The proxy uses [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) (or even [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)) and [`__setattr__` hooks](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) to handle arbitrary attributes. You are out of luck here, you can't detect what attributes either method will support outside of `hasattr()` and trying to set the attribute directly. Use `try...except` guarding:

   ```
   try:
       driver.console.con.input = 'something'
   except Attribute:   # exactly what exception object does this throw?
       # can't be set, not a writable attribute
       pass
   ```

   You may have to use a debugger or `print()` statement to figure out exactly what exception is being thrown (use a `try...except Exception as ex:` block to capture all exceptions then inspect `ex`); in the traceback in your question the exception message at the end looks decidedly non-standard. That project really should raise an `AttributeError` at that point.

Given the rather custom exception being thrown, my money is on option 2 (but option 1 is still a possibility if the `__get__` method on the descriptor throws the exception).

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of the try...except  approach but your answer supplied some additional details from under the hood. Thank you for the detailed answer!